# When should I use "das neue Buch" and "das neues Buch"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When should I use "das neue Buch" and "das neues Buch"? Can you make a sentence using both?

Comment: *Das neues Buch* is plain wrong, but when you have an indefinite article (*ein*), you would correctly write *Ein neues Buch*.

Answer (score 6):

> das neue Buch

is the correct form with a definite article.

> das neues Buch

is ungrammatical. Never use it.

You could, however, use:

- ein neues Buch (indefinite article)
- neues Buch (no article, very rarely used)

Comment: Neues Buch zu verkaufen, ungelesen. Nur Selbstabholung!

Comment: @infinitezero: Right, one of the most common cases to use the no-article form, and doesn't work like that in a complete sentence.

Comment: Ich kann mir trotzdem vorstellen, dass man umgangssprachlich "das (i)s nneues Buch" sagen kann, aber das ist dann halt eine sehr lässige Aussprache.

Comment: @Dan egal, wie schlampig die Aussprache auch sein mag, irgendeine Verzögerung zwischen *das* und *neues* müsste hörbar bleiben, da nicht nur ein, sondern gleich zwei kurze Wörter jeweils zu einem einzelnen Laut verkürzt werden.

Comment: Im Prinzip ja, aber das kann u.U. auch ganz verschwommen werden. Zwar kein besonders gutes Beispiel, aber trotzdem:
https://youtu.be/Xcqcni1PcFo?list=RDbY6059rr7BU&t=133
"das der Schlüssel"
Muttersprachler haben eine Tendenz, den richtigen Artikel auch in seiner Anwesenheit auszudenken, und daher kann das ganz unauffälig vorbeigehen.